# How to apply float precision (type specifier) in a conditional f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I have the following f-string I want to print out on the condition the variable is available:

```
f"Percent growth: {self.percent_growth if True else 'No data yet'}"
```

Which results in:

```
Percent growth : 0.19824077757643577
```

So normally I'd use a type specifier for float precision like this:

```
f'{self.percent_growth:.2f}'
```

Which would result in:

```
0.198
```

But that messes with the if-statement in this case. Either it fails because:

```
f"Percent profit : {self.percent_profit:.2f if True else 'None yet'}"
```

The if statement becomes unreachable.
Or in the second way:

```
f"Percent profit : {self.percent_profit if True else 'None yet':.2f}"
```

The f-string fails whenever the condition leads to the else clause.

So my question is, how can I apply the float precision within the f-string when the f-string can result in two types?

Comment: I formulated the question this way so it was clear no matter what condition it fails to even execute.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use another f-string for your first condition:

```
f"Percent profit : {f'{self.percent_profit:.2f}' if True else 'None yet'}"
```

Admittedly not ideal, but it does the job.

Comment: Another way is using `str.format` but I don't think it's any different. `f"Percent profit : {'{:.2f}'.format(self.percent_format) if True else 'None yet'}"`  This is as simple as it gets if OP insists putting the condition within the f string itself.

Comment: @Idlehands Isn't it strange though that I can format strings and use conditionals, but not both at the same time?

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock If both outcomes of the the conditional were the same, you could. I think the tricky part of your example is that your conditional will yield either a float _or_ a string.

Comment: @PatrickArtner see the OP’s question and code sample. The `if True` is a stand in for any conditional.

Answer (score 2):

I think the f string within f string answer is as simple as it gets, but if you want a little bit more readability, consider moving the condition *outside* the f string:

```
value = f'{self.percent_profit:.2f}' if True else 'No data yet'
print(f"Percent profit : {value}")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary for the formatter as well - no need to stack 2 f-strings like [Nikolas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949994/7505395) does:

```
for pg in (2.562345678, 0.9, None):   # 0.0 is also Falsy - careful ;o)
    print(f"Percent Growth: {pg if pg else 'No data yet':{'.05f' if pg else ''}}")
    # you need to put '.05f' into a string for this to work and not complain
```

Output:

```
Percent growth: 2.56235
Percent growth: 0.90000
Percent growth: No data yet
```